# jQuery's submit() won't get fired

Tags: jquery

I have the following code but it doesn't work I assume that the problem is around my function declaration but not sure how to debug it. Any help would be welcome.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){   
if ($('select#prod_category').val() == ''){
          $('select#prod_group').hide();
          }
if ($('select#prod_group').val() == ''){
          $('select#product').hide();
          } 
$("form#g_search select").change(function(){
    $("div#gutschein_filter form#g_search").submit(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = "/folder/" +
        encodeURI($("#prod_category").val()) + "/" +
        encodeURI($("#prod_group").val());
    });


  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What is your main **Objective**? explain detail..

Comment: I'm trying to organize my submitted url variables to can manipulte with htaccess

Answer (score 3):

```
$("div#gutschein_filter form#g_search").submit(function( event ){                                                     
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = "/folder/" +
    encodeURI($("#prod_category").val()) + "/" +
    encodeURI($("#prod_group").val());
});
```

I've found one problem in your code. Missing of `event` parameter to `submit` callback function.

Use ***firebug*** or such like debuggers to get errors. Here is about **[firebug for JavaScript](http://getfirebug.com/javascript/)**.

Comment: thanks fow your reponse. But adding event did not resolve my problem

Comment: @lgt explain your problem detail in your post. Better would be a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Hi I have been trying to summarize my problem on http://jsfiddle.net/lgtsfiddler/Yqune/3/, maybe you have an idea what I'm making wrong

Comment: okay I found the problem $("form#g_search select").change("submit",function(event) {});